# stop javascript execution till jquery JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, callback

I am calling a third party webservice using `getJSON` callback. The function does not have a `success` handler attached to the function and since it is third party, I cannot edit the code also. By the time I receive the response, some of the javascript function in the page already executes.

Is there any way I can delay the execution of the Javascript function till I receive the response data from web service except `setTimeout` method.

Answer (score 3):

#### Description

You can use jQuery's `.ajaxStart()` and `.ajaxComplete()` events to get noticed if your ajax call is running. You can create a bool variable, something like `isAjaxRunning` and put this around the other javascript. So if `isAjaxRunning` is true, dont execute other javascript.

#### More Information

- [jQuery.ajaxStart()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/)
- [jQuery.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)

Answer (score 1):

if you have access to the code you can make it synchonize by adding the attribute

`async : false` 
- then it won't be a asynchronous call like the normal ajax .

If you can post the sample code - that will give a clear picture.